# How do I send push notification on Android depending on the data from a REST API using Firebase?

Tags: android, rest, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have successfully setup Firebase and my Android app to work together. I can send notification from the Firebase console and receive perfectly. But, that's not what I want, I want to send notification depending on the data I receive from a REST API in JSON format(I'm using the USGS API). So I would like to notify my users when a major earthquake takes place. How do I achieve this? I'm pretty new to all this, it would be great if you could help me out.

Answer (score 3):

Once you implement Firebase in your app, you will receive `refreshedToken`, you need to send this to your Web Server so it has the updated token.
And implement a your own section on web to send Push notification with help from following process
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal using node.js script.

Just follow below instructions:
1. install fcm node

```
npm install fcm-node
```

2. paste below code & save file with name say "fcm_demo" with .js extension

   ```
   var FCM = require('fcm-node');
   var serverKey = 'YOURSERVERKEYHERE'; //put your server key here 
   var fcm = new FCM(serverKey);

   var message = { //this may vary according to the message type (single recipient, multicast, topic, et cetera) 
   to: 'registration_token', 
   data: {  //you can send only notification or only data(or include both) 
              my_key: 'my value',
              my_another_key: 'my another value'
         }
   };

   fcm.send(message, function(err, response)
   {
     if (err)
    {
      console.log("Something has gone wrong!");
    } 
     else 
    {
       console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
    }
   });
   ```

***Few points to remember :-***

You will get your server key from Firebase Console where you have registered your Project. (Just search there..).

You will get registration token from `refreshedToken`.

Before installing fcm-node, your machine must have pre-installed  `node.js` and `npm`. If you don't have node.js and npm previously installed, first install those components & then install fcm-node.

As you want to send notification depending on the data you receive from a REST API in JSON format, just copy your JSON format in `data` section of above `node.js` script.

Run above script from terminal as

```
node fcm_demo.js
```

If everything goes well, you will receive your notification.

Thanks. ;)

Comment: Thank you for this! I will try this out.

Comment: Sure.. If you stuck with any problem, please feel free to ask!